# In a js regexp should i escape angle brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use a regexp in my javascript code, that searches for a tag with its "less than" and "more than" brackets :

```
html = html.replace(/(\<\/ul\>\n\<ul\>)/gm,'');
```

It works perfectly, but jshint tells me "Unexpected escaped character '<' in regular expression."

My question is : is there a good reason to escape them ?

Comment: Why do you escape `<` and `>` in the first place? They are not special regex metacharacters in JS regex flavor.

Comment: "is there a good reason to escape them " - yes, there is, if you're going to use the same regex with other dialects (php, python etc).  e.g. a config file that will read both in backend and frontend.